# Unable to print in Jupyter Notebook using Pandas

Tags: data-cleaning, pandas, jupyter, ipython, data-wrangling

I am doing basic data analysis on an csv file in jupyter notebook

```
def answer_two():
    return (df['Gold']-df['Gold.1']).argmax()
answer_two
```

The above code snippet is to subtract two columns of the dataframe.I am expecting an answer in the form of a country name but I am getting the following output.

```
<function __main__.answer_two>
```

I am unable to figure out why this is happening .Occasionally ,the required output in the form of country name is coming but not running it everytime.

Comment: `answer_two()` not `answer_two`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `answer_two`, call `answer_two()`. you are referring to the function object now. You have to call the function.